# Positional arguments mismatching pivot table in python

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks like -

id    amt     qty   m_status       age    c_desc         present
1    95.00     1     Married       36.0    others           1
1    39.00     1     Married       36.0    others           1
2    72.00     2      Single       30.0    South            0
2    32.00     5      Single       30.0    others           0
3    267.61    4     Married       61.0    others           0
4    594.00    1     Single        51.0    South            1
4    550.00    5      Single       51.0    South            1

I want my final data frame should be -

id   south    others
1      0        2
2      2        5
3      0        4
4      6        0

I have done the code. But got this error -

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-56167b862c95> in <module>
      1 x = final_df_1.pivot_table(index=['id'], 
      2                      columns ='c_desc', values='qty', aggfunc='sum')
----> 3 total_qty_spend = x.reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)

/mnt/var/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    195         @wraps(func)
    196         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
--> 197             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    198 
    199         if not PY2:

TypeError: rename_axis() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

My code is -

```
final_df_1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

    x = final_df_1.pivot_table(index=['id'], 
                         columns ='c_desc', values='qty', aggfunc='sum')
    total_qty_spend = x.reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)
    total_qty_spend.fillna(0,inplace = True)

    total_qty_spend.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `axis=1` instead `1` and also is possible add parameter `fill_value=0` to [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for replace missing values created by pivot operation:

```
total_qty_spend = x.reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
```

All together:

```
x = final_df_1.pivot_table(index=['id'], 
                           columns ='c_desc', 
                           values='qty', 
                           aggfunc='sum',
                           fill_value=0)

total_qty_spend = x.reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
print (total_qty_spend)
   id  South  others
0   1      0       2
1   2      2       5
2   3      0       4
3   4      6       0
```